# how to run shell script command in ubuntu from php remote

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

This is the code I used to execute a script command from PHP. But it runs in the server itself and displays only the output in ubuntu browser.

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('mkdir Ubuntu');
?>
```

Comment: From the docs on `echo`: *Outputs all parameters. No additional newline is appended.* Just delete the `echo`

Comment: If your expecting this to run on the users machine then this isn't how PHP works.  It only runs on the server.

Comment: I think the question is not so clear, could you explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: ya i want to run this on users machine. @NigelRen

Comment: anyone know how to do it or send me a link with the reference material